# How to show $\int_0^1 \left( \frac{1}{\ln(1+x)} - \frac{1}{x} \right) \,dx$ converges?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I need to show that $$\int_0^1 \left( \frac{1}{\ln(1+x)} - \frac{1}{x} \right) \,dx$$ converges, given that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+} \left( \frac{1}{\ln(1+x)} - \frac{1}{x} \right) = \frac{1}{2}$$

I'm not sure how to do this because my text gave a very brief treatment on applying the limit comparison test for the improper integral of the second kind. Here is what I've tried:

I define the test function to be $g(t)=1$. Therefore,

$$\frac{\left( \frac{1}{\ln(1+x)} - \frac{1}{x} \right)}{g(t)} = \left( \frac{1}{\ln(1+x)} - \frac{1}{x} \right) \tag{1}$$

So, $(1)$ tends to $\frac{1}{2}$ as $t$ tends to $0^+$ and $$\int_0^1 g(t) \,dt$$ is convergent. Therefore, by the limit comparison test, the given integral is convergent.

Did I do the test correctly?

**EDIT**

My text's solution (which I find to be vague) is:

[image]

What does 'repair' the integrand mean?

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\int_0^1\bigg(\frac1{\ln(1-x)}+\frac1x\bigg)~dx~=~\gamma,~$ see [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Mascheroni_constant) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give a more general answer, which should explain what “repairing the function” means.

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function defined on the interval $(a,b]$ (where $a<b$) and that
$$
\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=r
$$
is finite.

Define $g(x)=f(x)$ for $a<x\le b$ and $g(a)=r$. Then $g$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$. Set
\begin{align}
F(x)&=\int_{x}^b f(t)\,dt &&\text{for $x\in(a,b]$}\\
G(x)&=\int_{x}^b g(t)\,dt &&\text{for $x\in[a,b]$}
\end{align}
The two functions $F$ and $G$ are continuous (even differentiable, by the fundamental theorem of calculus) and coincide on $(a,b]$, so
$$
\lim_{x\to a^+}F(x)=\lim_{x\to a^+}G(x)=G(a)
$$

Comment: Thank you. I understand your answer. So, in this case, there is no need to use the limit comparison test at all and does that mean my solution is nonsensical?

Comment: @mauna It's non nonsensical at all. It's not needed: basically, changing the value of a function at a point doesn't change its integrability and the value of the integral.

Answer (score 5):

For first, $\frac{1}{\log(1+x)}-\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^+$. Now:

$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{\log(1+x)}-\frac{1}{x}\right) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x-\log(1+x)}{x\log(1+x)} = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)}{x^2+O(x^3)}=\frac{1}{2}$$
hence $f(x)$ is continuous and bounded over $(0,1)$, and that implies that $f(x)$ is integrable.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{\log\left(1+x\right)}-\frac{1}{x}\right)dx=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^{+}}\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{\log\left(1+x\right)}-\frac{1}{x}\right)dx$$ now $\frac{1}{\log\left(1+x\right)}-\frac{1}{x}$
  is an decreasing function over $\left(\epsilon,1\right)$, so $$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^{+}}\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{\log\left(1+x\right)}-\frac{1}{x}\right)dx\leq\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^{+}}\max_{x\in\left[\epsilon,1\right]}\left(\frac{1}{\log\left(1+x\right)}-\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(1-\epsilon\right)\leq\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^{+}}\left(\frac{1}{\log\left(1+\epsilon\right)}-\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: I can see why $\frac{1}{\log\left(1+x\right)}-\frac{1}{x}$ is a decreasing function over $(\epsilon,1)$ but I don't know why the last inequality is true. Can you please further elaborate on this part?

Comment: @mauna I added some information.

Comment: Thank you. But I still don't understand it. This is the first time I am seeing the triangle inequality being applied to an expression that has an integral in it and I don't see where it comes into play. I am very surprised to see the integral sign in the left most of the inequality disappear. Geometrically, is the first half of the inequality saying that the area under the curve defined by the function,$f(x)$ less than a rectangle with the height of the defined as the max of $f(x)$ over the interval $[\epsilon,1]$. for a given $\epsilon$?

Comment: @mauna You have an positive function inside the integral, then you can maximize it taking the product of the maximum of the function and the length of the interval.

Comment: thank you. I get it now. Can you please also tell me how the the last expression in the inequality follows?

Comment: @mauna If $f(x)\leq g(x)$ then $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}f(x)\leq\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}g(x)$ (assuming the existence).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the kind of answer you expect; so, forgive me if I am off-topic.

Consider Taylor series, built at $x=0$, of $$\frac{1}{\log(1+x)}-\frac{1}{x} =\frac{x-\log(1+x)}{x\log(1+x)}$$ For the numerator, you have $$\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^5}{5}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ and for the denominator $$x^2-\frac{x^3}{2}+\frac{x^4}{3}-\frac{x^5}{4}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ Performing the long division, you then have $$\frac{1}{\log(1+x)}-\frac{1}{x} =\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x}{12}+\frac{x^2}{24}-\frac{19 x^3}{720}+\frac{3
   x^4}{160}-\frac{863 x^5}{60480}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ Integrating from $0$ to $1$, the approximation is $\frac{847319}{1814400}\approx 0.466997$ while the exact solution would be $\text{li}(2)-\gamma\approx 0.467948$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not aware of this technique. Unfortunately, it is definitely not what my text had in mind as it did not cover the li function. I've provided my text's solution. Can you please help me make sense of it?

Comment: I was not giving any thing about the logarithmic integral but just reporting, for your curiosity, the exact value. And you are welcome !

Answer (score 0):

I think "repair" means this.  Define function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{1}{\ln(1+x)} - \frac{1}{x},\qquad x>0
\\
\displaystyle\frac{1}{2},\qquad\qquad x=0
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, so it is integrable.