# How to evaluate the improper integral $(\sin(1/x))^2$ from 1 to infinity.

Tags: real-analysis

I am struggling to show that the improper integral $(\sin(1/x))^2$ from $1$ to infinity converges. After about half an hour of trying to integrate the function I looked on wolfram alpha and found the answer to include the sine integral.

This makes me doubt that evaluating the integral is the intended method to solve this function, as we have not studied the sine or cos integral. Also the question only asks if the integral converges, not to what value. So is there a different way I could show the integral converges, probably using the definition of a Riemann integral?

Comment: Try to substitute $u = \frac 1x$. (Not sure if it can be computed explicitely, but it will be obvious that it converges)

Answer (score 2):

Or, in my opinion, simpler: Just use that $0 \le \sin^2 \frac1x \le \frac1{x^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute 
$$\;u=\frac1x\implies du=-\frac{dx}{x^2}\implies dx=-\frac{du}{u^2}\implies\;$$

$$\int_1^\infty\sin^2\frac1x\;dx=\int_1^0\sin^2u\left(-\frac{du}{u^2}\right)=\int_0^1\left(\frac{\sin u}u\right)^2du$$

and the last one is a(n almost) Riemann integral as the function is continuous in $\;(0,1]\;$ and has a removable discontinuity at $\;x=0\;$ (in fact, it ie enough to have the function continuous *and bounded* in $\;(0,1]\;$ )

Comment: If a function is Riemann integrable over an interval does that guarantee that  the integral isn't infinite?

Comment: @user228742 That's part of the definition of "function Riemann integrable": it **must** be a number and this finite, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can do substitutions: use $1/x=t$, so $x=1/t$ and $dx=-dt/t^2$, so
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}\sin^2\frac{1}{x}\,dx=
\int_{1}^{0}-\frac{\sin^2t}{t^2}\,dt=
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin^2t}{t^2}\,dt
$$
Now, the function $t\mapsto\dfrac{\sin^2 t}{t^2}$ can be extended by continuity at $0$, so the integral is not even an improper one. See my answer at [How to show $\int_0^1 \left( \frac{1}{\ln(1+x)} - \frac{1}{x} \right) \,dx$ converges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217180/how-to-show-int-01-left-frac1-ln1x-frac1x-right-dx-conv)